# Сохранение react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, context

Вообщем я делаю веб приложение на `React js`. Сейчас делаю авторизацию и для хранения данных авторизованного пользователя решил использовать `React context`, но возникла проблема - при перезагрузке страницы данные из `context` изчезают.

Есть ли способ сохранить данные в `context` хотя бы до выхода из браузера? Возможно я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные пользователя нужно хранить в БД, т.е. для авторизации нужен сервер.
Context решает только одну задачу - удобное получение данных в компонентах с глубокой вложенностью.
Если вы понимаете, что не готовы к написанию сервера, то вы можете хранить данные пользователя в localStorage, но так можно делать только в самых первых начинаниях в изучении web-разработки.

Comment: Если я буду получать данные с сервера, заносить их в куки ,а из куки заносить в context это будет правильно?

Comment: @Antonio, а зачем в этом случае куки?

Comment: Вам не нужно заносить их в куки. В куки(или localStorage) должен находиться токен, который сервер отдает при авторизации, а вот уже с помощью него вы получаете данные и сохраняете их в состоянии react-приложения. Но на context вы далеко не уедете. Вам стоит так же познакомиться c менеджерами состояний: Effector, Mobx, Redux и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно

Comment: Рад был помочь, удачи! Если будут еще вопросы, ты вы можете мне написать в вк: https://vk.com/lucien_glue